# Django REST Framework + django-rest-auth: Error during setup of Angular helper module

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm trying to setup the angular-django-registration-auth AngularJS module to help smooth the login/logout process for my in-progress web app, which has an AngularJS frontend consuming a Django REST Framework API and django-rest-auth for authentication/registration.

The rest-auth endpoints for login and logout work just fine, however I'm having issues injecting the Angular helper module as described on the module's [github page](https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth). I've added the requisite dependency to my main app declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngRoute', 'xeditable', 'angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp']);
```

But I get several of the following errors on load:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp
```

This error seems pretty clear initially- that the app hasn't been declared, however I'm not sure how to do so beyond the injection above (I'm new to a lot of this in general, and definitely the frontend part). Even if I remove the `angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp` dependency from the `var app =` declaration above, I still get instances of the `$injector:nomod` error, which seem to originate from the included `djangoAuth.js` file that contains all of the helper functions, and comes straight from the provided module.

The module repo hasn't been active since early last year, but a recently opened issue notes some changes that have to be made for Angular 1.4+ (I'm using 1.5) so it seems that it largely still works. I made those syntax changes but still hit the error. Have I neglected to do something simple as far as declaring the auth helper app?

I know this app has it's own dependencies, so could that be what I missed? I thought the files I added would handle those, so I haven't installed anything outside of `angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out, I believe it's related to something with my development environment (Windows, Python 3.4, Visual Studio 2015 + Python Tools for Visual Studio).

I simply declared the `angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp` at the top of my JS file, above the line where I declared my own app with the registration app as a dependency. So it looks like this:

```
angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp', []);    

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngRoute', 'xeditable', 'angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp']);
```

I'm not sure why this is necessary, as the person I'm working with (not using VS + PTVS) doesn't require the extra declaration in order to successfully load the module. I've had to add similar declarations for a couple other Angular modules I'm using, while my friend has had no issue simply adding them as dependencies in the main app declaration.